# What is the list of valid @SuppressWarnings warning names in Java?

Tags: java, eclipse, warnings, compiler-warnings, suppress-warnings

What is the list of valid `@SuppressWarnings` warning names in Java?

The bit that comes in between the `("")` in `@SuppressWarnings("")`.

Comment: This question is really nice and answers are useful. If someone from the JCP looks at it, you should realize how messy it is to add a suppress warning. There is no convention on case, hyphen, camel case, it's just a plain mess, it would be lovely to standardize this.

Comment: I see `"ProhibitedExceptionDeclared"` within Eclipse Collections Framework (`org.eclipse.collections.impl.block.function.checked.ThrowingFunction`), and that is not listed below.

Answer (score 293, accepted):

It depends on your IDE or compiler.

Here is a [list](http://www.breakitdownblog.com/supported-values-for-suppresswarnings/) for Eclipse Galileo:

> - **all** to suppress all warnings
> - **boxing** to suppress warnings relative to boxing/unboxing operations
> - **cast** to suppress warnings relative to cast operations
> - **dep-ann** to suppress warnings relative to deprecated annotation
> - **deprecation** to suppress warnings relative to deprecation
> - **fallthrough** to suppress warnings relative to missing breaks in switch
>     statements
> - **finally** to suppress warnings relative to finally block that don’t
>     return
> - **hiding** to suppress warnings relative to locals that hide variable
> - **incomplete-switch** to suppress warnings relative to missing entries
>     in a switch statement (enum case)
> - **nls** to suppress warnings relative to non-nls string literals
> - **null** to suppress warnings relative to null analysis
> - **restriction** to suppress warnings relative to usage of discouraged or
>     forbidden references
> - **serial** to suppress warnings relative to missing serialVersionUID
>     field for a serializable class
> - **static-access** to suppress warnings relative to incorrect static
>     access
> - **synthetic-access** to suppress warnings relative to unoptimized
>     access from inner classes
> - **unchecked** to suppress warnings relative to unchecked operations
> - **unqualified-field-access** to suppress warnings relative to field
>     access unqualified
> - **unused** to suppress warnings relative to unused code

[List](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/guide/jdt_api_compile.htm) for Indigo adds:

> - **javadoc** to suppress warnings relative to javadoc warnings
> - **rawtypes** to suppress warnings relative to usage of raw types
> - **static-method** to suppress warnings relative to methods that could be declared as static
> - **super** to suppress warnings relative to overriding a method without super invocations

[List](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tasks/task-suppress_warnings.htm) for Juno adds:

> - **resource** to suppress warnings relative to usage of resources of type Closeable
> - **sync-override** to suppress warnings because of missing synchronize when overriding a synchronized method

Kepler and Luna use the same token list as Juno ([list](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tasks/task-suppress_warnings.htm)).

Others will be similar but vary.

Comment: In what instances would suppressing a null warning be useful?

Comment: @Jesse: When the compiler is wrong (i.e. a "'Stupid Flanders' warning"). Try compiling: `void foo( Object o ) { boolean b; if ( ( b = o == null ) ) o = new Object(); o.toString(); }`. Some environments (e.g. NetBeans 7.3 w/ Java 6 JDK [1.6.0_41]) will generate `"o possibly null"` at the `o.toString()` call even though `o` can't be null at that point.

Comment: @cletus : Is it possible to add types of warnings in eclipse?  The problem is that one of our team members uses IntelliJ, and that IDE has other suppress warning types that give warnings in Eclipse :)  In Eclipse Indigo you can set in the preferences: Ignore unused SuppressWarnings tokens, but that doesn't seem to work ...

Comment: `semicolon` does not seem to work in luna? :( Can someone verify if `semicolon` is indeed valid?

Comment: What's the value for suppressing the "synchronization on non-final field" warning?

Comment: links are broken

Comment: "It depends on your IDE or compiler." OK, so where is the list for the javac compiler? That's the one most of us I would imagine will be ultimately targeting, as it's likely most people will deploy their projects built with javac, not with Eclipse/IntelliJ/whatever.

Comment: Ah, It looks like there is a list in the [javac docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/specs/man/javac.html) for e.g. Java 17. Unfortunately it doesn't look like Eclipse recognizes all of them, e.g. `@SuppressWarnings("try")`.

Answer (score 52):

All values are permitted (unrecognized ones are ignored).  The list of recognized ones is compiler specific.

In [The Java Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/annotations/predefined.html) `unchecked` and `deprecation` are listed as the two warnings required by The Java Language Specification, therefore, they should be valid with all compilers:

> Every compiler warning belongs to a category. The Java Language Specification lists two categories: deprecation and unchecked.

The specific sections inside [The Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/) where they are defined is not consistent across versions. In the Java SE 8 Specification `unchecked` and `deprecation` are listed as compiler warnings in sections **9.6.4.5. @SuppressWarnings** and **9.6.4.6 @Deprecated**, respectively.

For Sun's compiler, running `javac -X` gives a list of all values recognized by that version.  For 1.5.0_17, the list appears to be:

- all
- deprecation
- unchecked
- fallthrough
- path
- serial
- finally

Comment: `javac -X` is more general, but `javac --help-lint` gives a nice list of warning names.

Comment: @kol that's because of time travel... this answer is from way back :) Java 5-16 uses `javac -help -X` and Java 17-21 uses `javac --help-lint` to list the actual `-Xlint` options.

Answer (score 49):

The list is compiler specific. But here are the values supported in [Eclipse](http://help.eclipse.org/help33/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/guide/jdt_api_compile.htm):

> - **allDeprecation**   deprecation even inside deprecated code
> - **allJavadoc**   invalid or missing javadoc
> - **assertIdentifier**  occurrence of assert used as identifier
> - **boxing**    autoboxing conversion
> - **charConcat**    when a char array is used in a string concatenation without being converted explicitly to a string
> - **conditionAssign**   possible accidental boolean assignment
> - **constructorName**   method with
>     constructor name
> - **dep-ann**   missing @Deprecated
>     annotation
> - **deprecation**   usage of deprecated type or member outside deprecated code
> - **discouraged**   use of types matching a discouraged access rule
> - **emptyBlock**    undocumented empty block
> - **enumSwitch**, **incomplete-switch**     incomplete enum switch
> - **fallthrough**   possible fall-through case
> - **fieldHiding**   field hiding another variable
> - **finalBound**    type parameter with final bound
> - **finally**   finally block not completing normally
> - **forbidden**     use of types matching a forbidden access rule
> - **hiding**    macro for fieldHiding, localHiding, typeHiding and maskedCatchBlock
> - **indirectStatic**    indirect reference to static member
> - **intfAnnotation**    annotation type used as super interface
> - **intfNonInherited**  interface non-inherited method compatibility
> - **javadoc**   invalid javadoc
> - **localHiding**   local variable hiding another variable
> - **maskedCatchBlocks**     hidden catch block
> - **nls**   non-nls string literals (lacking of tags //$NON-NLS-)
> - **noEffectAssign**    assignment with no effect
> - **null**  potential missing or redundant null check
> - **nullDereference**   missing null check
> - **over-ann**  missing @Override annotation
> - **paramAssign**   assignment to a parameter
> - **pkgDefaultMethod**  attempt to override package-default method
> - **raw**   usage a of raw type (instead of a parametrized type)
> - **semicolon**     unnecessary semicolon or empty statement
> - **serial**    missing serialVersionUID
> - **specialParamHiding**    constructor or setter parameter hiding another field
> - **static-access**     macro for indirectStatic and staticReceiver
> - **staticReceiver**    if a non static receiver is used to get a static field or call a static method
> - **super**     overriding a method without making a super invocation
> - **suppress**  enable @SuppressWarnings
> - **syntheticAccess, synthetic-access**     when performing synthetic access for innerclass
> - **tasks**     enable support for tasks tags in source code
> - **typeHiding**    type parameter hiding another type
> - **unchecked**     unchecked type operation
> - **unnecessaryElse**   unnecessary else clause
> - **unqualified-field-access, unqualifiedField**    unqualified
>     reference to field
> - **unused**    macro for unusedArgument, unusedImport, unusedLabel, unusedLocal, unusedPrivate and unusedThrown
> - **unusedArgument**    unused method argument
> - **unusedImport**  unused import reference
> - **unusedLabel**   unused label
> - **unusedLocal**   unused local variable
> - **unusedPrivate**     unused private member declaration
> - **unusedThrown**  unused declared thrown exception
> - **uselessTypeCheck**  unnecessary cast/instanceof operation
> - **varargsCast**   varargs argument need explicit cast
> - **warningToken**  unhandled warning token in @SuppressWarnings

Sun JDK (1.6) has a shorter [list](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javac.html#options) of supported warnings:

> - **deprecation**      Check for use of depreciated items.
> - **unchecked**  Give more detail for unchecked conversion warnings that are mandated by the Java Language Specification.
> - **serial** Warn about missing serialVersionUID definitions on serializable classes.
> - **finally** Warn about finally clauses that cannot complete normally.
> - **fallthrough** Check switch blocks for fall-through cases and provide a warning message for any that are found.
> - **path**     Check for a nonexistent path in environment paths (such as classpath).

The latest available javac (1.6.0_13) for mac have the following supported warnings

> - **all**
> - **cast**
> - **deprecation**
> - **divzero**
> - **empty**
> - **unchecked**
> - **fallthrough**
> - **path**
> - **serial**
> - **finally**
> - **overrides**

Comment: The Eclipse list here looks to compiler flags and not SuppressWarning annotations (check the last part of the doc you linked).

Comment: They are both. By setting the compiler flags you tell the compiler what kind of warnings you want. With the annotations you can suppress these warnings in specific places in your code.

Comment: I think the list is shorter for Eclipse. See latest galileo docs, list of available tokens for SupressWarnings is explicit there: http://help.eclipse.org/galileo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/guide/jdt_api_compile.htm

Comment: I tried @SuppressWarnings("raw") in Eclipse 3.5 and it does not work - I get a warning that it "raw" is not a valid value for this annotation.

Comment: me too. Unfortunatel that the jsp support isn't as flushed out as the java support is.

Answer (score 9):

I noticed that `//noinspection` can be auto-generated in **IntelliJ**

- make sure you have not already a plan `@SuppressWarninigs` before the statement
- Now you can auto-generate the specific `//noinspection` by hitting **Alt+Enter** when you have the warning selected and then use the **right arrow key** to see the *Suppress for ...* option

*Ended up here when I wanted to suppress a "switch has too few case labels" warning from IntelliJ. I did not find a complete List for IntelliJ's `@SuppressWarning` support but `//noinspection` did the trick for me.*

Comment: You can add @SuppressWarnings("SwitchStatementWithTooFewBranches") for that as well.

Comment: Unfortunately the *Supress for ...* option when clicking ALT+ENTER is not always available

Comment: `//noinspection SwitchStatementWithTooFewBranches` before the `switch` works as well for me.

Answer (score 8):

A new favorite for me is `@SuppressWarnings("WeakerAccess")` in IntelliJ, which keeps it from complaining when it thinks you should have a weaker access modifier than you are using. We have to have public access for some methods to support testing, and the `@VisibleForTesting` annotation doesn't prevent the warnings.

ETA:
"Anonymous" commented, on the page @MattCampbell linked to, the following incredibly useful note:

> You shouldn't need to use this list for the purpose you are
>   describing. IntelliJ will add those SuppressWarnings for you
>   automatically if you ask it to. It has been capable of doing this for
>   as many releases back as I remember.
>
> Just go to the location where you have the warning and type Alt-Enter
>   (or select it in the Inspections list if you are seeing it there).
>   When the menu comes up, showing the warning and offering to fix it for
>   you (e.g. if the warning is "Method may be static" then "make static"
>   is IntellJ's offer to fix it for you), instead of selecting "enter",
>   just use the right arrow button to access the submenu, which will have
>   options like "Edit inspection profile setting" and so forth. At the
>   bottom of this list will be options like "Suppress all inspections for
>   class", "Suppress for class", "Suppress for method", and occasionally
>   "Suppress for statement". You probably want whichever one of these
>   appears last on the list. Selecting one of these will add a
>   @SuppressWarnings annotation (or comment in some cases) to your code
>   suppressing the warning in question. You won't need to guess at which
>   annotation to add, because IntelliJ will choose based on the warning
>   you selected.

Comment: I had the trouble of getting the mouse to hover and open the "Edit inspection profile setting" menu. It is the tiny arrow next to the Show Context options entry.

Answer (score 3):

I just want to add that there is a master list of IntelliJ suppress parameters at: https://gist.github.com/vegaasen/157fbc6dce8545b7f12c

It looks fairly comprehensive.  Partial:

```
Warning Description - Warning Name

"Magic character" MagicCharacter 
"Magic number" MagicNumber 
'Comparator.compare()' method does not use parameter ComparatorMethodParameterNotUsed 
'Connection.prepare*()' call with non-constant string JDBCPrepareStatementWithNonConstantString 
'Iterator.hasNext()' which calls 'next()' IteratorHasNextCallsIteratorNext 
'Iterator.next()' which can't throw 'NoSuchElementException' IteratorNextCanNotThrowNoSuchElementException 
'Statement.execute()' call with non-constant string JDBCExecuteWithNonConstantString 
'String.equals("")' StringEqualsEmptyString 
'StringBuffer' may be 'StringBuilder' (JDK 5.0 only) StringBufferMayBeStringBuilder 
'StringBuffer.toString()' in concatenation StringBufferToStringInConcatenation 
'assert' statement AssertStatement 
'assertEquals()' between objects of inconvertible types AssertEqualsBetweenInconvertibleTypes 
'await()' not in loop AwaitNotInLoop 
'await()' without corresponding 'signal()' AwaitWithoutCorrespondingSignal 
'break' statement BreakStatement 
'break' statement with label BreakStatementWithLabel 
'catch' generic class CatchGenericClass 
'clone()' does not call 'super.clone()' CloneDoesntCallSuperClone
```

Answer (score 3):

### Official sources for the list of supported values

- [JSL 9.6.4.5 `@SuppressWarnings`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se21/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.6.4.5)
- [`javac` docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/specs/man/javac.html#option-Xlint-custom)
- CLI of your actual `java`

  - Java 5-16 `javac -help -X`
  - Java 17-21 `javac --help-lint`
- In case you need older documentation, https://javaalmanac.io seems to be a pretty good reference.
- Anything else that your IDE, or static code analyzer can understand. For example

  - Eclipse has a few additional ones that look like Java offical ones
  - IntelliJ IDEA has inspections that can be suppressed the same way.
  - Checkstyle, PMD, etc. can also use this same annotation.

### `javac -Xlint` options across JDK versions

Based on the above here's an official-ish list from Oracle/OpenJDK JDKs.

| Name | Since* | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| all | 5 | Enable all warnings |
| none | 6 | Disable all warnings |
| preview | 11 17<sup>std</sup> | Warn about use of preview language features. |
| auxiliaryclass | 8 | Warn about an auxiliary class that is hidden in a source file, and is used from other files. |
| cast | 6 | Warn about use of unnecessary casts. |
| classfile | 7 | Warn about issues related to classfile contents. |
| deprecation | 5 11<sup>std</sup> | Warn about use of deprecated items. |
| dep-ann | 7 | Warn about items marked as deprecated in JavaDoc but not using the @Deprecated annotation. |
| divzero | 6 | Warn about division by constant integer 0. |
| empty | 6 | Warn about empty statement after if. |
| exports | 17 | Warn about issues regarding module exports. |
| fallthrough | 5 | Warn about falling through from one case of a switch statement to the next. |
| finally | 5 | Warn about finally clauses that do not terminate normally. |
| lossy-conversions | 21 | Warn about possible lossy conversions in compound assignment. |
| missing-explicit-ctor | 17 | Warn about missing explicit constructors in public and protected classes in exported packages. |
| module | 9 | Warn about module system related issues. |
| opens | 9 | Warn about issues regarding module opens. |
| options | 7 | Warn about issues relating to use of command line options. |
| output-file-clash | 21 | Warn when an output file is overwritten during compilation. This can occur, for example, on case-insensitive filesystems. Covers class files, native header files, and source files. |
| overloads | 8 | Warn about issues regarding method overloads. |
| overrides | 6 | Warn about issues regarding method overrides. |
| path | 5 | Warn about invalid path elements on the command line. |
| processing | 7 | Warn about issues regarding annotation processing. |
| rawtypes | 7 | Warn about use of raw types. |
| removal | 9 11<sup>std</sup> | Warn about use of API that has been marked for removal. |
| requires-automatic | 9 | Warn about use of automatic modules in the requires clauses. |
| requires-transitive-automatic | 9 | Warn about automatic modules in requires transitive. |
| serial | 5 | Warn about Serializable classes that do not have a serialVersionUID field. Also warn about other suspect declarations in Serializable and Externalizable classes and interfaces. |
| static | 7 | Warn about accessing a static member using an instance. |
| strictfp | 17 | Warn about unnecessary use of the strictfp modifier. |
| synchronization | 17 | Warn about synchronization attempts on instances of value-based classes. |
| text-blocks | 17 | Warn about inconsistent white space characters in text block indentation. |
| this-escape | 21 | Warn when a constructor invokes a method that could be overriden in an external subclass. Such a method would execute before the subclass constructor completes its initialization. |
| try | 7 | Warn about issues relating to use of try blocks (i.e. try-with-resources). |
| unchecked | 5 6<sup>std</sup> | Warn about unchecked operations. |
| varargs | 7 | Warn about potentially unsafe vararg methods. |

* I only checked the commonly occurring 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 17, 21 versions.
<sup>std</sup> ones are standard according to JLS version evolution.

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be a much more complete list, where I found some warnings specific to Android Studio that I couldn't find elsewhere (e.g. `SynchronizeOnNonFinalField`):

https://jazzy.id.au/2008/10/30/list_of_suppresswarnings_arguments.html

Oh, now SO's guidelines contradict SO's restrictions.
On one hand, I am supposed to copy the list rather than providing only the link.
But on the other hand, this would exceed the maximum allowed number of characters. So let's just hope the link won't break.

Answer (score 1):

**JSL 1.7**

[The Oracle documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-9.html) mentions:

- `unchecked`: Unchecked warnings are identified by the string "unchecked".
- `deprecation`: A Java compiler must produce a deprecation warning when a type, method, field, or constructor whose declaration is annotated with the annotation @Deprecated is used (i.e. overridden, invoked, or referenced by name), unless: [...] The use is within an entity that is annotated to suppress the warning with the annotation @SuppressWarnings("deprecation"); or

It then explains that implementations can add and document their own:

> Compiler vendors should document the warning names they support in conjunction with this annotation type. Vendors are encouraged to cooperate to ensure that the same names work across multiple compilers.

Comment: It is not true that `unchecked` is the only one endorsed by the standard; the very next section from the one you quoted says deprecation warnings should not be produced when "The use is within an entity that is annotated to suppress the warning with the annotation `@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")`"

Answer (score 1):

If you're using SonarLint,
try above the method or class the whole squid string:
    @SuppressWarnings("squid:S1172")