# all SuppressWarnings values?

Tags: java

would be great if there is a list with all values one can use with @SuppressWarnings in java.

if these values are dependent on the compiler lets say ant in netbeans. shouldn't ant then provide a full list of all supported values?

Comment: See also: [What is the list of valid `@SuppressWarnings` warning names in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1205995/572834)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Here; [http://www.breakitdownblog.com/supported-values-for-suppresswarnings/](https://web.archive.org/web/20100209022416/http://www.breakitdownblog.com/supported-values-for-suppresswarnings). Note these are for main Java libraries; other APIs might have their own.

> - **all** to suppress all warnings
> - **boxing** to suppress warnings relative to boxing/unboxing operations
> - **cast** to suppress warnings relative to cast operations
> - **dep-ann** to suppress warnings relative to deprecated annotation
> - **deprecation** to suppress warnings relative to deprecation
> - **fallthrough** to suppress warnings relative to missing breaks in switch statements
> - **finally** to suppress warnings relative to finally block that don’t return
> - **hiding** to suppress warnings relative to locals that hide variable
> - **incomplete-switch** to suppress warnings relative to missing entries in a switch statement (enum case)
> - **nls** to suppress warnings relative to non-nls string literals
> - **null** to suppress warnings relative to null analysis
> - **rawtypes** to suppress warnings relative to un-specific types when using generics on class params
> - **restriction** to suppress warnings relative to usage of discouraged or forbidden references
> - **serial** to suppress warnings relative to missing serialVersionUID field for a serializable class
> - **static-access** to suppress warnings relative to incorrect static access
> - **synthetic-access** to suppress warnings relative to unoptimized access from inner classes
> - **unchecked** to suppress warnings relative to unchecked operations
> - **unqualified-field-access** to suppress warnings relative to field access unqualified
> - **unused** to suppress warnings relative to unused code

- **varargs** to suppress warnings about unsafe usages of variable arguments (varargs) methods, in particular, those that contain non-reifiable arguments.

Comment: link appears to be dead, this is why link only answers are not answers!

Answer (score 16):

Look at [Javac compiler documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javac.html#xlintwarnings), `Xlint` option. All these could be disabled by `@SuppressWarnings`

Comment: Duplicate of the accepted answer

Comment: That's true, but look at the date. My answer was the first. It's sad that has 0 upvotes when it's duplicate of older accepted one, as you correctly said.

Comment: link appears to be dead, this is why link only answers are not answers!

Comment: It's not even a duplicate of the accepted answer. This one's link is to the official doc instead of to a blog, which is better.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javac.html#xlintwarnings

Answer (score 4):

There cannot be. These are extensible. For example, **PMD** respects `@SuppressWarning("PMD")`.