# Content of Collection never updated warning in Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I created a simple Counter class:

```
public class Counter<T> extends HashMap<T, Long> {
    public Counter() {
    }

    public void increase(T key) {
        put(key, getOrDefault(key, 0l) + 1);
    }
}
```

In my code, I call the increase() method and then use Map method to access the data, e.g.

```
  Counter<Integer> counter = new Counter<>();
  for (Integer i: ... some collection ...)
      counter.increase(i);
```

Intellij highlights the declaration of `counter` (first line in last snippet) with warning colour, and the tooltip message says

> Contents of collection are queried, but never updated.

Obviously I can just ignore this warning, but is there a way to convince Intellij nothing is wrong with my code?

I am using 14.0.2 community edition.

Comment: since the Intellij warning message specifies collection, is it possible it is talking about some other collection, not Counter (which extends Map which is not a collection...)

Comment: The warning is on that variable. Sorry, my question may not have been clear enough to start with. I edited in hope it's clearer now.

Comment: so where is the highlighted line of code?

Comment: I thought that was clear enough without it. Added it now.

Comment: It is strange indeed why the IDE thinks there is any problem...

Comment: `merge(key, 1L, Long::sum)` would probably be a better way to express this anyway.

Answer (score 8):

IntelliJ IDEA does not realize that the increase() method updates the map, because it is not part of the standard map API. To remove the warning, you can suppress the inspection.

However, a better design would be to make your Counter class encapsulate a HashMap, rather than extend it. This will make sure that the users of your class will only call the APIs that are appropriate, and will not corrupt your data by calling put() or other modification methods directly.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. In my scenario I am comfortable with users having access to the HashMap if they like, and I have not much interest and writing many methods that only delegate :-)

Comment: Is there any @SuppressWarning argument to deal with this inspection?

Comment: Yes. You can press Alt-Enter on any inspection highlight and select the suppress action from the menu.

Answer (score 6):

You can also try adding `@SuppressWarnings("MismatchedQueryAndUpdateOfCollection")` to ignore it.

Comment: Where do you put this suppression?  And where can I find a list of suppression messages as this doesn't seem to do it for me.

Comment: @ScottBiggs I guess we'll never know

Comment: @ScottBiggs, you can browse to this stackoverflow link (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2037326/all-suppresswarnings-values) to ignore many SuppressWarnings cases. The SuppressWarnings annotation is annotated by Target(value={TYPE,FIELD,METHOD,PARAMETER,CONSTRUCTOR,LOCAL_VARIABLE}), so you can put to many piece of your code like method or class.