# hashmap are updated , but never queried android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, hashmap

I using hashmap but it gives me that message at the android studio

"Contents of collection 'userMap' are updated, but never queried"

my code:

```
HashMap<String , String> userMap = new HashMap<String , String>();
        userMap.put("username" , name);
        userMap.put("fullname" , fullName);
        userMap.put("country" , country);
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30458975/content-of-collection-never-updated-warning-in-intellij-idea

Comment: that's not helped me

Comment: It means that userMap is not returned neither accessed... It's a warning that you are instantiating then initialize the collection but there is no explicit call to it.

Comment: Can you post the code where you are using contents of the map. Also check if that code is ever executed ( i.e. in case of a method is it invoked or in case of statements in an invoked method then are those statement inside a code block that is executed )

Comment: updated : you have instansiated the hashmap and have put the entries in it. Queried : Use the hashmap or its contents (map maps key to values, are you using get() or similar API of hashmap)

Answer (score 3):

It means that userMap is not returned neither accessed... It's a warning that you are instantiating then initialize the collection but there is no explicit call to it.

Before u make a call to it:
[image]

After that:
[image]