# What do @SuppressWarnings("deprecation") and ("unused") mean in Java?

Tags: java, android, suppress-warnings

What do these lines in my Java or Android project mean?

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
```

Answer (score 134, accepted):

The `@SuppressWarnings` annotation disables certain compiler warnings. In this case, the warning about deprecated code (`"deprecation"`) and unused local variables or unused private methods (`"unused"`). [This article explains the possible values.](http://blog.bangbits.com/2008/05/suppresswarnings-annotations.html)

Comment: For a more official list of possible values, see [What is the list of valid @SuppressWarnings warning names in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77331135/253468).

Answer (score 7):

One more thing: you can not only add them inline, but also [annotate methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/SuppressWarnings.html). For example

```
@Override
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
}
```

Yet, it is recommended to use the smallest scope possible

> As a matter of style, programmers should always use this annotation on the most deeply nested element where it is effective. If you want to suppress a warning in a particular method, you should annotate that method rather than its class.

Answer (score 6):

In Java, `@SuppressWarnings` are use to restrict the compiler to show the certain warning on  the console screen.

E.g

```
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
CheckBox transferredField = new CheckBox("is transferred");
```

if I don't use `transferredField` variable in my code then your Eclipse IDE never show the warning that you are not using this `transferredField` variable in your code.

Answer (score -4):

the `@SuppressWarnings("unused")` and others i have tried,but it don't work,and i always use the method say gradle in this project to

```
lintOptions{
        checkReleaseBuilds false
        abortOnError  false;
        disable 'deprecation'
    }

    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:unchecked" << "-Xlint:deprecation"
    }
```

Comment: Please don't disable warning across your entire project. Disabling a warning should be scoped to the most specific level you can, where you know exactly why it is ok to ignore in your case. Hiding them for the entire project will also hide legitimate concerns you should consider changing rather than ignoring.