# Application crashes after notification

Tags: android, android-notifications

*Notification is working fine but problem is it crashed after clicking button
*It says add @ Add@SuppressWarnings 'deprication' to n
         and
         add @ Add@SuppressWarnings 'deprication' to onclick

```
public class testInput extends Activity {

    Button Setbutton;
    Location location, locationA, locationB;
    LocationManager locationManager;
    NotificationManager nm;
    public static final int uniqueId =1;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.showcoords);

        nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        nm.cancel(uniqueId);

        Setbutton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnShowLocation);

        Setbutton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(testInput.this, goIn.class);
                PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(getBaseContext(),
                        0, intent, 0);
                String body = "This is a Notification";
                String title = "Test";
                Notification n = new Notification(R.drawable.route, body,
                        System.currentTimeMillis());
                n.setLatestEventInfo(testInput.this, title, body, pi);
                n.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_ALL;
                nm.notify(uniqueId, n);
                finish();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: can you show your logcat here

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7398023

Comment: sree @Ramkiran thanks 4 ur help.. however i found out that i forget to  give vibration permission...