# Eclipse: contradicting warnings

Tags: java, eclipse, aspectj, suppress-warnings

Here's the code snippet:

```
class MyClass {
    private native void foo();
}
```

For the above, Eclipse (namely, 3.7.0) gives a warning

> The method foo() from the type MyClass is never used locally

Alright, but when I try to suppress the warning:

```
class MyClass {
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private native void foo();
}
```

It complains

> Unnecesary @SuppressWarnings("unused")

So, is there any way to make it stop complaining?

**Update**

Sorry for the incomplete information - this warning is only displayed in an AspectJ project. Once I create a simple Java project and put my class in it, all works fine.

As far as I understand, AspectJ uses its own compiler, so this warning must be generated by it. I'm using AspectJ Development Tools plug-in:

```
Version: 2.1.3.e37x-20110628-1900
AspectJ version: 1.6.12.20110613132200
```

Comment: Funny, I don't have the second warning (under Eclipse 3.5)

Comment: ... and I do not see the first warning - "The method foo() from the type MyClass is never used locally". Strange!

Comment: can you try 'Project > Clean' and then do a rebuild. Maybe the first warning is a stale marker..

Comment: Clean and full rebuild don't help at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside of a Java project, this produces no warnings:

```
class MyClass {
    private native void foo();
}
```

This, however, produces a `Unnecessary @SuppressWarnings("unused")` warning:

```
class MyClass {
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private native void foo();
}
```

Inside of an AspectJ project, the first example produces a `The method foo() from the type MyClass is never used locally` warning and the second example produces the same warning as in a Java project.  This is likely an AspectJ bug.  I'd recommend raising an issue on the AspectJ bugzilla.

https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/

The AspectJ compiler is a fork of the JDT compiler from Eclipse 3.3.  So, it is likely that this bug was originally in Eclipse 3.3.  Now that Java 7 is available, AspectJ will likely migrate to being Eclipse 3.7 or 3.8 based and it will pick up the fix from the JDT compiler.  But it is worth raising a bug anyway.

Comment: Yep, it seems like an Eclipse/AspectJ bug, so I've filed an issue: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=213755.

Answer (score 2):

The list of `@SuppressWarnings` is compiler specific. In Eclipse,

**unused** is  macro for unusedArgument, unusedImport, unusedLabel, unusedLocal, unusedPrivate and unusedThrown

The whole list is here : [the list of valid @SuppressWarnings supported in Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1205995/what-is-the-list-of-valid-suppresswarnings-warning-names-in-java/1206052#1206052)

Comment: Just to be more precise, @SuppressWarnings is not specific to Eclipse.  However, the list of warnings suppressed by that annotation is compiler specific.

Answer (score 0):

I just tried and I don't get the "unnecessary..." warning. Are you sure that the warning is issued by the java compiler and not by some other tool such as checkstyle or findbugs?

Anyway, there are few situations, where an unused private method makes sense.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is indeed a case when there's no way to avoid declaring unused private method.

Answer (score 0):

It's working for me. I'm running Eclipse Indigo like you.