# Disable warning in IntelliJ for one line

Tags: java, intellij-idea, warnings, line

I have a Java code line where IntelliJ displays a warning. How do I silence the warning in that particular line, without affecting warnings displayed in other lines?

In this question it's irrelevant what the actual warning is: now I'm not seeking advice on how to improve the quality of a specific piece of Java code, but I want to know in general how to prevent IntelliJ from displaying a warning on a specific Java source line.

Comment: That's really not enough detail for someone to answer. What warning? What's on the line?

Comment: More information about the warning would be helpful. Warnings do exist for a reason and its often better to fix the underlying problem than to ignore the warning.

Comment: In this question the specific warning is irrelevant. I want to know in general what can I do to disable warnings reported by IntelliJ for a specific line (in addition to fixing my code), for all possible warnings.

Comment: For instance: Intellij complains that `password.replaceAll(".","*")` is usually a mistake.  It thinks you meant `replaceAll("\.",...)`.  Thanks, but no.  So now I want to acknowledge and suppress the warning.  I don't want it to hang around.

Answer (score 105, accepted):

Mostly in IntelliJ, you can click on the line and `Alt+Enter`, and it will have options for suppressing the warning, among other things.

Comment: It doesn't have such an option in my case. It offers some options to fix the root cause of the warning, but I don't want that now. I just want to get rid of the warning.

Comment: @kat, you need to press right arrow key to open the inspection sub-menu from where you can suppress it for current line, which will add the annotation automatically.

Comment: It works now as you (Ryan Stewart and CrazyCoder) wrote: I press F2 to jump to the next warning, then I press Alt-Enter to see the warning, then I press the Right arrow key to get options to fix the problem, then I select the appropriate Ignore... option. FYI Just hovering the mouse over the warning line displays a tooltip using which it's impossible to get rid of the warning.

Comment: Current IntelliJ allows to use "Analyze" : "Inspect Code" which opens a lower pane.  On the right pane there is a convenient "Suppress for statement" on the right side.  Needs a big screen and a mouse, though.

Comment: I do not find any of the suggestions or comments on a Mac.

Comment: 2022 and intellij still has very bad UI design with respect to this issue.  So hard to find the suppress option.

Comment: This suggestion is not often true. For example, here is my suggestions after doing alt+enter on a warning: https://i.imgur.com/XrGUzGm.png

Answer (score 73):

Expanding upon Ryan Stewart's answer, in IntelliJ, use `Alt+Enter`, then select the first sub-menu, then the last item: `Suppress for statement`.

[image]

**Update**

Using IntelliJ IDEA 13, I noticed an additional menu item: "Suppress for statement with comment".  This will use the IntelliJ style `//noinspection unchecked`.  If you select "Suppress for statement", IntelliJ will insert this text: `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")`.

Comment: Thanks. However this will add
//noinspection deprecation

instead of
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")

Comment: `@SuppressWarnings()` is Java, `//noinspection` is JavaScript

Comment: @MartinVysny if you want `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` use `Suppress for method` instead of `Suppress for statement`

Comment: Is there a list of all the valid tags for //noinspection?

Answer (score 17):

Depending on the warning you can use `@SuppressWarnings`. Eg:

```
@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
yourLineWhichIsDeprecated;
```

[Take a look at this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1206052/155137) for a pretty long list of warnings you can suppress. Check the other posts on that topic for more details.

Comment: Thank you for the background information, it's good to know how SuppressWarning works. However, I was looking for an IntelliJ-specific solution.

Answer (score 13):

In IntelliJ 15 the inline "yellow bulb" and alt-enter menus don't offer to suppress the inspection for 1 line.

There are more options when running the inspections via the Menu: `Analyze -> Inspect Code...`.

Then on the Inspection panel the right side offers various options.
Some of text in the right hand panel is clickable. Note that usually the problem resolution function (quick fix) is also available.

[image]

(Apparently @tino already noticed this in a comment, but I missed his comment the first time. I'm adding this as full answer to make the important bit I personally missed easier to find.)

Comment: At least an answer that doesn't rely to alt-enter menu which, as stated, don't offer the "Disable inspection" or "Suppress for..." in some cases.

Comment: `Analyze -> Inspect Code...` Beautiful. It has the interface right there +1

Comment: thank you ! you save me, with the new interface this is in Code > InspectCode. The generate interface is a bit different but still solve the problem !

Answer (score 4):

Just one more note. If you are looking for a answer to **suppress all warnings** for a next line (or part of the code). It might be a reason for a several cases:

- Idea doesn't provide error name, or suggestions
- Number of warnings for next line is too large

You can use just:

```
    //noinspection ALL
```

Answer (score 4):

## *Problems* panel

The *Problems* panel shows a list of warnings and errors in our code. There we can peruse the various issues with our code, working through the list one-by-one. This feature arrived [in IntelliJ 2020.2](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2020/08/working-with-code-problems-in-intellij-idea/#problems_tool_window).

In at least IntelliJ 2021.2, and perhaps earlier, we can suppress a warning within that panel.

When selecting a problem point, the right-side pane of the *Problems* panel shows a *Suppress* widget. This pop-up menu displays items for various ways to suppress the warning.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

1. Click on the complaining area that has a wavy line 〰️ beneath it
2. A light bulb  appears, click the light bulb
3. Select the suppress statement option

[image]

4. An no inspection comment will be added above current line `//noinspection CssInvalidPropertyValue`

5. The complaining disappear

Answer (score 0):

**When compiling code using Kotlin language and IntelliJ here is a hint**

Here is a link to the github source where the compiler warnings have their origin and where the default error messages output by the Kotlin compiler are defined

[kotlin/compiler/frontend/src/org/jetbrains/kotlin/diagnostics/rendering/DefaultErrorMessages.java](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/29beed9b2160ce4c1b2bfc4766e6a53f772c9a8f/compiler/frontend/src/org/jetbrains/kotlin/diagnostics/rendering/DefaultErrorMessages.java#L62)

If the compiler outputs ***"Variable ''{0}'' is never used"*** it origins from this line form DefaultErrorMessages.java

```
MAP.put(UNUSED_VARIABLE, "Variable ''{0}'' is never used", NAME);
```

To suppress the warning you can put a @Suppress() annotation before an unused variable in your code like this:

```
@Suppress("UNUSED_VARIABLE")
var y: Int = 3
```

So the trick if the IntelliJ does not help you pop up suggestions pressing Alt+ENTER at a highlighted expression is to look inside *DefaultErrorMessages.java* if you can find the error message and the keyword to supress a particular warning using @Suppress(..names)

This topic is not marked "Kotlin" but at least marked IntelliJ

Answer (score 0):

//noinspection unchecked,ConstantConditions

@SuppressWarnings does not work in every place

Answer (score 0):

As other questions point out, there are several options to achieve what are you asking for. A more comprehensive list of the options available can be found in the official documentation [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/disabling-and-enabling-inspections.html#suppress-inspections).

Answer (score 0):

The above did not work e.g. for puppet files (# noinspection, no pop up to disable for just the line). As a workaround, it's possible to [disable for just one file](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/205812019/comments/360002269980)

> Don't really understand why this change was made. But here's how you
> turn off inspections for a single file:
>
> Open the file in question. Hover over the green checkmark at the upper
> right of the editor window. You should see "PHP: All Problems" (or
> some variation) as a link there. Click that and select "None", that
> will apply to the entire file (and just that file).
>
> It's not clear that that's what it does, nor at all clear that
> Hector's feature got moved here, but once you get it it's easy to
> change.

[image: how to disable screenshot from intellij forum]