# Remove unnecessary @SuppressWarnings/noinspection in IntelliJ

Tags: java, intellij-idea

We're using IDEA IntelliJ for our Java coding. In the past some heavily used `@SuppressWarnings` annotations or `noinspection` comments to suppress warnings/inspections in the IDE others disabled some inspections. Now we start using the same inspection base for all programmers. However the code now is cluttered with annotations and `noinspection` comments that are not necessary any more for the inspections are disabled.

Is there a way to remove all `@SuppressWarnings` annotations or `noinspection` comments in the whole project that are not necessary any more due to disabled inspections in IntelliJ?

Comment: with editor you could use: 'find and replace' facility

Comment: I don't think there is an automatic way, so you might have to take the time to do a project-wide find &  replace. Of course that'll find all of them, not just the unnecessary ones, though

Comment: did you try '@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")' ?

Comment: look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19398420/3669309

Comment: I'd rather avoid the find-and-replace way for in a project with zillions lines of code this is quite error prone.

Comment: @Tupac, it seems you misunderstood my questions: I do not want to add a `@SuppressWarning`, I want to remove them if they are unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA [will have an inspection](https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2018/09/intellij-idea-2018-3-eap-git-submodules-jvm-profiler-macos-and-linux-and-more/) which will highlight redundant usages of @SuppressWarning annotation in editor starting from version 2018.3. You can run this inspection on whole project and quickly remove all unneeded annotations.