# Intellij "Warning: The jjs tool is planned to be removed from a future JDK release jjs> what to do"

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm using intellij for Java development, and when I run the application, it shows an error message saying "Warning: The jjs tool is planned to be removed from a future JDK release jjs>", then it gets stuck at the line and none of my System.out.println print anything at all. I'm not sure what to do with it.

Comment: That's a deprecation warning, not an exception and will not keep your code from compiling or running. There's some other problem in your code that causes it to fail but since you didn't bother posting any code, there's no way to tell what's happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the short term, you don't need to do anything.  This is just a warning.  Your code will keep running until you upgrade to a Java release that removes the Nashorn Javascript interpreter.

The deprecation is in accordance with [JEP 335](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/335).  A Java release for Nashorn *removal* is not proposed in the JEP, and it hasn't been removed yet as of Java 13.

**UPDATE** - Nashorn was actually removed in Java 15+ (source [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nashorn_(JavaScript_engine))).

In the long term, you will probably need to find a different Javascript interpreter for your application to use.  You could suppress the warnings for now (for example: [Disable warning in IntelliJ for one line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7798908/disable-warning-in-intellij-for-one-line)), but if you do that there is a risk that you will forget that you did it, and then get a nasty shock when you upgrade to the (future) release.

If Intellij itself is using `jjs`, then the Intellij developers will need to address this.