# Get rid of "integer division in floating-point context" warning

Tags: java, intellij-idea, warnings, suppress-warnings

Is it possible to get rid of the "integer division in floating-point context" warning, in this line of code:

```
int num = 14;
int roundedValue = (Math.round(num / 10) * 10);
```

Comment: Which Java compiler is producing this warning?  Is it `javac`?  An IDE's compiler?  Which IDE?

Comment: It is a Java 11 (Project SDK is set to Java version 11.0.5) project, on Intellij

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well one solution would be

```
int roundedValue = (num / 10) * 10;
```

Note that integer division truncates, so the `Math.round` call is superfluous in the above.

On the other hand, this may not give you the answer you are expecting.  A possible alternative that gives a different (but maybe more correct) answer is:

```
int roundedValue = Math.round(num / 10.0) * 10;
```

(You will see different results for `num = 16`, for example.)

In other words, this warning could actually be pointing out a bug in your code!  Making warnings "just go away" is a bad idea if the warning is telling you something important.

---

If you really need to suppress a warning on a specific line with Intellij; see [Disable warning in IntelliJ for one line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7798908/disable-warning-in-intellij-for-one-line).  (Using the IDE shortcut means you don't have to know the compiler specific warning name.)

Answer (score 0):

You could try casting your integer to a floating point:

```
int num = 14;
int roundedValue = (Math.round(((float) num) / 10) * 10);
```