# Android Java Compiler directive to disable warnings for a single line of code

Tags: android, compiler-construction, warnings

I want to suppress a compiler warning by number. I saw it done by following the line of code with some special comment.

You know Murphy's law? I think this is one case.
When I don't need it, I bump all the time over code that has this kind of directive. Loks somehting like

```
static int num;   //!NLNS201
```

Now that I need it I cannot find it anywhere.

EDIT:
I cannot believe nobody knows what  am talking about! I rephrased the question, maybe it was unclear.

Comment: There's [`@SuppressWarnings`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/SuppressWarnings.html), is that what you meant?

Comment: @JoaqchimSauer No, it is not, but I was mistaken. I meant the NON_NLS tags. But those are meant for a different purpose. I am using SuppressWarnings already. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I found it. But it is not what I thought it is.

The **$NON-NLS-x** tags, are used by Eclipse to suppress only literal strings warning aimed at language internationalization.

I am using instead @SupressWarnings("all") before the variable declaration.

See this post for a good reference on [@SuppressWarnings arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1205995/what-is-the-list-of-valid-suppresswarnings-warning-names-in-java)