# @SuppressWarnings for the invocation of the varargs with un-cast null

Tags: java, junit4, variadic-functions, suppress-warnings

What string should I use in `@SuppressWarnings("....")` to remove the warning I get in this unit test of a method with varargs:

```
/**
 * Calling {@link #readFiles(String, String...)} with just one arg and a null
 * works, but you have to do a null check on the varargs in case it is null.
 */
@Test
public void callMethodWithOneArgAndNull() {
   readFiles("C:/Temp", null);
}
```

Eclipse gives the following warning for this:

> The argument of type null should explicitly be cast to String[] for
>   the invocation of the varargs method readFiles(String, String...) from
>   type TestVarArgs. It could alternatively be cast to String for a
>   varargs invocation

This is good; it is expected. I am also unit testing what happens when I cast the null.

But for the purposes of this single test, I want to suppress that specific warning, i.e. I don't want to use `@SuppressWarnings("all")`. I have tried every string mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1206052/257233) to [What is the list of valid @SuppressWarnings warning names in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1205995/what-is-the-list-of-valid-suppresswarnings-warning-names-in-java) and none of them seem to catch this warning.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To my understanding, this is not a warning you can suppress with a specific annotation. You have to make an explicit cast to make the warning go away - or suppress all warnings.

Also, consider testing both possible casts, i.e. `(String[]) {null}` and `(String) null`, to make sure your method doesn't choke on "no files" nor on a "null filename" input.

Comment: Good pointers @einpoklum, thanks. I wrote up these tests here: http://robertmarkbramprogrammer.blogspot.com.au/2013/03/nulls-and-varargs.html

Answer (score -1):

You can use @supresswarnings (unchecked) annotation.