# Suppress JPA warning "locally" (for one specific place in Java code, not for the whole project) in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, jpa, warnings, suppress-warnings

*The question is about **suppressing specific JPA warnings in Eclipse**, the code below is just for illustration.*

I am using JPA for persistence, implemented by Hibernate. The pure JPA doesn't generally like the `mappedBy = "bindServiceId"` part, although the Hibernate implementation understands it and does what I expect.

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "bindServiceId")
private List<ServiceType> serviceTypes = new ArrayList<>();
```

However, I have an ugly message in my Eclipse project:

```
In attribute 'serviceTypes', the "mapped by" attribute 'bindServiceId' has an invalid mapping type for this relationship.
```

I *know* that the message can be suppressed *globally* in Eclipse (Mars) | `Window` | `Preferences` | `Java Persistence` | `JPA` | `Errors/Warnings` | `Attribute has invalid mapping for this relationship`, as in the picture below:

[image]

However the solution is not ideal:

1. It influences globally the whole IDE (or at least the whole project), and I do not want to suppress the warning for *all* the instances
2. It is not in the code so it is not part of the codebase (we don't store Eclipse files in GIT) and all the team members would have to set it in their IDEs, too.

**Question**

Is it possible to suppress a single JPA warning only locally, for one selected place, like you can do with standard compiler messages using the [@SuppressWarning](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1205995/2886891) annotation?