# How do I suppress warning "Synchronization on a non-final field"

Tags: java

Is it possible to suppress this kind of warning?

**Note:** I am not looking for suppressing all warnings(like this     `@SuppressWarnings("all")` ), but only the mentioned type.

Comment: I suggest you make the field final. Using non-final fields is error prone.  Note: this is not a Java warning so it depends on which tool you are using.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I am using Android Studio. I am reading a book related to android gaming and they use a non-final field which they update from time to time. Also the field is synchronized in both class where is accessed therefore it seems to be safe.

Comment: Update: the field is set only once, theoretically it could be injected via constructor and set as final, however I see they have a setter method as a convention in a interface that I inherit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For Intellij, put this annotation on the class that has the warnings

```
@SuppressWarnings("SynchronizeOnNonFinalField")
```

[This](https://jazzy.id.au/2008/10/30/list_of_suppresswarnings_arguments.html) lead me to the tag to use for suppression and trial and error lead me to put it on the class instead of on the field or synchronized statement. :-P

Comment: NOTE: I'm doing this in Android Studio...I'm assuming it also works for Intellij for normal Java projects.

Comment: It works on both - tested it. Thank you as well for the link which helped you find the annotation tag

Answer (score 3):

If you're using IntelliJ, it looks like it's `@SuppressWarnings("SynchronizationOnLocalVariableOrMethodParameter")`. Otherwise it depends. You might find the answer on the list here: [What is the list of valid @SuppressWarnings warning names in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1205995/what-is-the-list-of-valid-suppresswarnings-warning-names-in-java)

Note that the warning is usually correct. In most cases you should just use a `final` field.

Comment: I am using Android Studio but it should be the same. I tested on both and does not work the suppress you mention above.

Answer (score 0):

This would help you,

> All values are permitted (unrecognized ones are ignored). The list of
>   recognized ones is compiler specific.
>
> 'unchecked' and 'deprecation' are required by the Java Language
>   Specification, and so should be valid with all compilers. For Sun's
>   compiler, running 'javac -X' gives a list of all values recognized by
>   that version. For 1.5.0_17, the list appears to be:
>
> all deprecation unchecked fallthrough path serial finally

Please refer this, same has discussed here [What is the list of valid @SuppressWarnings warning names in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1205995/what-is-the-list-of-valid-suppresswarnings-warning-names-in-java)