# Treat Java warnings differently

Tags: java, eclipse

I want to ask if there is a way to treat same type of warnings differently. I mean you can choose how to treat every warning (like warning unused, error unchecked cast and so on), but can I tell the compiler to treat one unused warning as error and ignore another (somehow specify where to treat as error and where to ignore it)?

Comment: `@SuppressWarnings(“unused“)` and code style settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [@SuppressWarnings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/SuppressWarnings.html) annotation. The warnings that can be suppressed are listed here: [What is the list of valid @SuppressWarnings warning names in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1205995/what-is-the-list-of-valid-suppresswarnings-warning-names-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

You have two options:

- Explicitly suppress warnings by adding a directive in each file
- Instruct the compiler to suppress warnings for all files

---

The `@SuppressWarnings` annotation allows you to suppress a warning, and can be applied to most Java blocks. Most IDEs will create a `@SuppressWarnings` annotation for you, as one of the hint options when a warning occurs.

---

`man javac` describes the `-Xlint` command line parameter.

There's a long list of options, for example if you want to disable the "raw types" warning:

```
javac -Xlint:-rawtypes ...
```

Most IDEs and build systems provide ways of passing parameters to `javac` -- check the documentation for yours.