# What is the list of valid @SuppressWarnings warning names in Gosu?

Tags: intellij-idea, warnings, compiler-warnings, suppress-warnings, gosu

What is the list of valid @SuppressWarnings warning names in Gosu?

The bit that comes in between the ("") in @SuppressWarnings("").

There is already an SO answer for Java but I'm interested in suppressing the warning that my variable type can be inferred (passing an inferred block variable as a function parameter does not compile so I'm using an explicitly typed variable).

Java answer: [What is the list of valid @SuppressWarnings warning names in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1205995/what-is-the-list-of-valid-suppresswarnings-warning-names-in-java)

Comment: You are not supposed to type these manually, use IDE suppression: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/suppressing-inspections.html.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that. When I choose that, IntelliJ does nothing and the warning remains.

Comment: You may want to file a ticket at https://github.com/gosu-lang/gosu-lang/issues.

Comment: I decided to change my code so that I don't need to suppress a warning. Now I'm passing an inline block to the helper function and my block calls the local function (rather than having a local variable block). It's unfortunate since it creates another stack level just to call a function when the function could just be passed since it has the same signature as the block.