# How to audit violations ignored via @SupressWarnings

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

Is there a way to see all the violations that are being ignored via `@SuppressWarnings`?
I know that we can see everything marked as a false positive in the tool, but what about what was ignored due to the annotation. Is there a way to audit everything that was ignored?

For example, by annotating a variable with `@SuppressWarnings("squid:S2039")`, will disable the rule [Member variable visibility should be specified](https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-2039), and it won't show up on SonarQube, which is expected. However, if we want to see everything that was suppressed, is there a way to see it in the tool?

Answer (score 0):

You may enable the [Track uses of "@SuppressWarnings" annotations](https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-1309) rule. It is possible to configure a whitelist of warnings which should be accepted like `serial,unchecked`. List of the "standard" warnings is here: [What is the list of valid @SuppressWarnings warning names in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1205995/4944847)